# iOS NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios

I m using below mentioned line in a function

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

And I m calling this function a no of time (e.g. 100 times). So my problem is that initially for about 60 times or more it is working properly but after that it gives me "BAD_EXC_ACCESS"

Function is given below

```
+ (NSString *) recvToFile:(NSString *)_fileName {

@try {
    int _sz = [self recvNumber:4];
    uint8_t t[_sz];
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSMutableData *fileData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        long _pos = 0;
        NSString *_fullPath = _fileName;
        while (_sz > _pos) {
            long _c = [m_sin read:t maxLength:_sz];
            _pos += _c;
            data = [NSData dataWithBytes:t length:_c];
            if([Misc checkFileExists:_fileName]==nil)
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:_fullPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
            [fileData appendData:data];
        }
    [fileData writeToFile:_fullPath atomically:YES];
    NSDictionary *attr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:_fullPath error:nil];

    long long length = [[attr valueForKey:@"NSFileSize"] intValue];
    if (length >= _sz)
        return (_fullPath);
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
}
return (nil);
}
```

And I m calling this function every time i receive a file. I want to save file from bytes

Comment: We need more code. There is nothing wrong with this line alone.

Comment: I have added code for my function

Answer (score 0):

You should not initialize data here:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

just initialize the variable to nil;

```
NSMutableData* data = nil;
```

Comment: Then where should i initialize it 
And after all how is it working for some of the calls

Comment: The initialization of this variable is unnecessary, because you assign a new object to this pointer in the next step: data = [NSData dataWithBytes:t length:_c];

Comment: I tried using your code but after this line where ever i m initializing any variable it gives the same error there - "BAD_EXC_ACCESS"

Comment: Try to set an exception breakpoint. In which line will the exception occur?

Comment: in my code just after NSMutableData* data = nil;
i.e. NSMutableData * *fileData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
After that I applied same action to this line as well making it to 
NSMutableData *fileData = nil;
Then it gave me error in NSString** _fullPath = _fileName;
so after that it is giving me that same error in every initialization

Comment: You can't initialize fileData to nil, because later you will append to it.

Comment: Then its giving the same error at fileData initialization
pls help me

Comment: but Dave, when i commented out that fileData initialization then why it was giving me same error at NSString initialization and when I removed this NSString _fullpath initialization then it was again giving me error in next initialization

Comment: No idea, I can imagine, that the problem is not in this code, but other parts of your project. Maybe you can try to investigate the with Leaks in the Instruments.

Comment: Anyways Dave, Thanks a lot for giving your precious time

Answer (score 0):

Try adding data like this to nsmutabledata

```
    [data appendBytes:t length:_c];
```